# How to add Batang font to ShareLaTeX

Tags: fontspec, languages, sharelatex

The Batang font supports CJK languages. The following example (from https://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/how-to-use-unicode-in-latex-by-luatex-or-xetex/)  works fine with TeXShop, but produces an error with ShareLaTeX: ! The font "Batang" cannot be found. How can one add the Batang font to ShareLaTeX ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Batang}

\begin{document}
\section{ASCII English}
Hello world.
\section{European}
¡Hola!, Grüß Gott, Hyvää päivää, Tere õhtust, Bonġu
          Cześć!, Dobrý den, Здравствуйте!
\section{CJK}
(Chinese) 你好, 早晨, (Japanese)こんにちは, (Korean, hangul) 안녕하세요

\end{document}
```

Comment: Batang is an MS font, I think. If the licence permits it, and if ShareLaTeX allows, you can upload the font in order to use it. Otherwise, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the licences, ShareLatex doesn't provide any fonts other than the ones included in the LaTeX base system. One can manually add a font to a project tough: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/XeLaTeX. The font file can be imported in ShareLateX.

[image]